# import axios causes problems in vue v3 and vite

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vite

> import axios from 'axios';

results in vite throwing

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default

Example Code

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import TheContainer from './components/TheContainer.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        TheContainer
    }
})
app.axios = axios;
app.$http = axios;
app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
app.mount('#app');
```

This is using axios 0.21.1 and vue 3.0.5

Trying to work out what is wrong... vuejs v3 cookbook sadly uses a call to the axios 0.14 code via a cdn

Comment: you can use the native `fetch` method instead of axios. Of course, only when it comes to simple requests and you don't need to use any of axios extra tools.

Comment: yes I know, but I was hoping to use the vue-auth library which wants axios for auth against an api

Comment: I couldn't reproduce - used `npx create-vite-app vite-test` then `yarn add axios`, then your code above with simple app.axios.get(...) in main and another in App. Can you flesh out details to reproduce? Version `"vite": "^1.0.0-rc.13"`

Comment: yes I'm running vite 2.0.0 - its looking more like a vite problem and vite's issue log suggests it falls in "won't fix"

Comment: Please see [Vite package - rollup.config.js](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/rollup.config.js) - `import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'` which says here [@rollup/plugin-commonjs README](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs) - ***A Rollup plugin to convert CommonJS modules to ES6, so they can be included in a Rollup bundle***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Redaxios](https://github.com/developit/redaxios) is a modern remake of axios.

```
import axios from 'redaxios';
// use as you would normally
```

This solved my problem with vite and axios. Works in webpack too.

Comment: sounds like a good solution... I've kinda abandoned axios under vue v3 since I can use fetch with vuex

Comment: Solved it for me

Comment: Redaxios doesn't yet support interceptors, so this didn't work for me. There is a feature request for it: https://github.com/developit/redaxios/issues/9

Answer (score 4):

You should install a bundled es module of axios  :

remove the current version:

```
 npm uninstall axios
```

then run:

```
 npm install @bundled-es-modules/axios --save
```

then use it like :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import TheContainer from './components/TheContainer.vue';
import axios from 'axios/axios.js';

//create an axios instance in order to use it globally with same config
const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },

})


const app = createApp({
    components: {
        TheContainer
    }
})

app.config.globalProperties.axios = instance;

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @BoussadjraBrahim this has solved a huge problem for me.
I can now build & run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is in Vite 2.x

[issue #174](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/174) and [issue 162](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/162) suggests that vite would prefer to have to deal with proper ESM modules instead of fixing them within itself (fair call)..

So as of vite 2.0.0-beta50 I'm going to go with building it using fetch and discarding vue-auth (which looks horribly complex for vue v3 anyway)

EDIT: never got to the bottom of this, but since I was building this in Homestead/Vagrant within Laravel - I found taking it completely out of that environment seemed to solve the problem.. I also noticed Vite didn't always notice code changes within the Homestead/laravel environment - so it might be caching or other things... anyways I took it out and things worked fine

Comment: Still not reproducible with `vite 2.0.0-beta50`, axios is working fine in a minimal app.

Comment: The issues cited are misleading in the case of axios - #174 (citing an `axios` problem) is old and closed off to #162, which cites a different library `remote-redux-devtools`, which is still problematic, whereas `axios` ***seems*** to works now (not sure if in every scenario).

Answer (score 1):

So, this issue just took me some time to resolve and I'd like to share my experience hoping it helps someone.

Although, some of the solutions in this answer helped to solve the initial problem, I had other problems further along the way. For example, when I installed `redaxios` I noticed it was not sending the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in the request headers (required by my backend service, Laravel Sanctum).

At the end what really solved my issue was simply deleting the `node_modules` directory and a fresh install (`yarn`). I think vite had a cached version of installed directories and no matter how many times I reinstalled `axios` or switched between the packages it kept showing some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should install this vite plugin [@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs).

```
npm install @originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs --save-dev
```

Add the plugin to your `vite.config.ts` and you are good to go.

```js
import { viteCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default {
    plugins: [
        viteCommonjs()
    ]
}
```

That is all

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './adminroutes'

import axios from 'axios'
window.axios = axios
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

const app = createApp({})

app.use(router)
app.mount('#adminapp')
```